# emacsclient: create a frame if a frame does not exist

Tags: emacs, emacsclient

I start emacs server using

```
emacs --daemon
```

then open files using

```
emacsclient filename.ext
```

but the first file has to be opened using

```
emacsclient -c filename.ext
```

in order to create a new frame which can be later used by subsequent files without using `-c` command line flag for emacsclient.

I want to automate this. "if there is no emacs frame, emacsclient should create a frame else it should use the current frame". How can it be done?

Comment: When I do `man emacsclient` it doesn't tell me about a `-c` option. Do you know what versions exhibit this behavior?

Comment: @dmckee `emacsclient -c` is new to the much improved emacsclient in Emacs 23.

Answer (score 16):

This is like dimitri's solution, but it handles the case when emacs was launched as `emacs --daemon`. `emacs --daemon` makes a hidden window that causes `xprop` to give a false positive when checking for an existing window.

```
#!/bin/bash

emacsclient -n -e "(> (length (frame-list)) 1)" | grep -q t
if [ "$?" = "1" ]; then
    emacsclient -c -n -a "" "$@"
else
    emacsclient -n -a "" "$@"
fi
```

Comment: one can put this in a function nicely in ,say, `.bashrc` file: `myemacsclient () {_here goes the code_}`, so that no extra script file is required.

Comment: Very nice. It should ship with emacs!

Comment: Thanks, @kkm! Updated with your suggestion.

Comment: You can also just match the string in the shell itself instead of spinning up a pipe and a `grep` process: `case $(emacsclient -n -e '(> (length (frame-list)) 1)') in t) emacsclient -c -n -a "" "$@";; nil) emacsclient -n -a "" "$@";; esac`. (That looks terrible in a comment, but I think it's pretty readable when split over at least four lines like this: `case ... in`, `t)   emacsclient ...;;`, `nil) emacsclient ...;;`, and `esac`).

Answer (score 7):

You can first create a frame if there isn't one already, then open the file in a now existing frame. Here's a snippet that creates a frame on the initial display if there isn't any frame now opened on a window display. You may wish to tweak this in a number of ways, such as checking whether there is already a frame on the display with `x-display-list`. You need `(require 'cl)` in your `.emacs. This may require some adaptation to work on Windows or Aqua.

```
emacsclient -e '(unless (find-if (lambda (f)
                                   (let ((p (frame-parameters f)))
                                     (assq '\''window-system p)))
                                 (frame-list))
                  (make-frame-on-display (getenv "DISPLAY")))'
emacsclient filename.ext
```

Comment: This is what I'm after, but I'm getting the error `Symbol’s function definition is void: find-if`. Any idea why? (Running GNU Emacs 25.2.2.)

Comment: @aioobe Do you have `(require 'cl)` in your init file? If not add it.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the emacs-client.sh script I use under Linux to do exactly what you ask for:

```
#!/bin/sh

xprop -name emacs >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
if [ "$?" = "1" ]; then
    emacsclient -c -n -a "" "$@"
else
    emacsclient -n -a "" "$@"
fi
```

Comment: This answer needs more upvotes!

Comment: This seems to get confused when you kill the emacs frame.  At that point the emacs server is still running and the xprop  line returns 0 so it won't open up a new frame after the first time.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Jim Hunziker's solution does not seem to have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think adding Gilles' function to `server-switch-hook` might do what you want.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to get `emacs --daemon` working to test it.

```
(add-hook 'server-switch-hook
          (lambda ()
            (unless (find-if (lambda (f)
                               (let ((p (frame-parameters f)))
                                 (assq 'window-system p)))
                             (frame-list))
              (make-frame-on-display (getenv "DISPLAY")))))
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution is to force the creation of a frame after starting the daemon:

```
function em() {
  emacs --bg-daemon --display=:0
  # Forces emacs to notice I'm using X as well.
  emacsclient --create-frame --display=:0 --no-wait
}
```

and then I never have to use --create-frame.

Comment: That doesn't address the issue of calling 'emacsclient -a="" file'  when there is no frame.  Jim Hunziker's reply is the cleanest.

Answer (score 0):

On OSX I just define this function (similar to Jim Hunziker's approach)

```
emacs () { pgrep -xiq emacs && emacsclient -n $@ || emacsclient -n -c --alternate-editor="" $@; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Jim Hunziker's answer does not quite work for me (in some situations frame-list returns two items even though there is no X frame). Assuming you only use one DISPLAY, the following works:

```
#!/bin/bash

emacsclient -n -e "(null (cl-remove-if (lambda (frame) (null (display-graphic-p frame))) (frame-list)))" | grep >/dev/null nil
if [ "$?" = "1" ]; then
    emacsclient -c -n -a "" "$@"
else
    emacsclient -n -a "" "$@"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another version that also works in tty/console mode:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                          

emacsclient -n -e "(if (> (length (frame-list)) 1) 't)" | grep t                                                                     
if [ "$?" = "1" ]; then                                                                                                              
    if [ "$DISPLAY" = "" ]; then                                                                                                     
        emacsclient -c -a "" "$@"                                                                                                    
    else                                                                                                                             
        emacsclient -c -n -a "" "$@"                                                                                                 
    fi                                                                                                                               
else                                                                                                                                 
    if [ "$DISPLAY" = "" ]; then                                                                                                     
        emacsclient -a "" "$@"
    else
        emacsclient -n -a "" "$@"
    fi
fi
```

(Based on Jim Hunzikers answer)